# Set disable for button Titanium

Tags: button, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a button and when click that button display an option dialog..Click item of option dialog and set title of button with name of item correspond..After set title for button,I want to disable button(can't click button or click button but dont' have event).
I set as follow but not true..

```
button.enable=false;
```

Can you help me..

Comment: Hey, If you ask any question and got any response (answer). then plz, give us feedback or comment necessary.

Comment: The guy is asking a legitimate question, so why the downvote? A quick view at the documentation (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button) reveals that the enabled property isn't documented.

Answer (score 6):

@user1478916
you Code have missing "enable" replace with "enabled"

```
   button.enabled=false;
```

Since SDK 3.3.0 This is deprecated on Android. Use touchEnabled property instead.

Comment: Since SDK 3.3.0

This is deprecated on Android. Use touchEnabled property instead.

Comment: Yes Falko, you are Right Thanks for comment :)